# How to call ajax function on submitting form through javascript in android, phonegap and jquerymobile

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, cordova

I have html form with two input fileds and submit button.

When i click on submit button it goes in my javascript function...but it does not call the ajax function written in it.

Instead of calling ajax function the page gets reloaded

Answer (score 3):

You not only have to use `event.preventDefault()` (or `return false`) in your event handler but you have to specifically disable the AJAX navigation for the form so jQuery Mobile doesn't do it's own form submission:

Here is one way using `data-ajax` (recommended):

```
<form data-ajax="false">
```

You can also do this by changing a default of jQuery Mobile when the `mobileinit` event fires:

```
<script src="jQuery-Core.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).bind("mobileinit", function(){
   $.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false;
});
</script>
<script src="jQuery-Mobile.js"></script>
```

Notice the order of the `<script>` tags. The downside to this method is that it disables AJAX navigation for all elements, not just the single form you're dealing with, that's why I recommend using the data attribute: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0-rc.1/docs/api/globalconfig.html

Answer (score 0):

have you disabled your form submit action using

```
e.preventDefaults()
```

can you show some of your code ?

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
  function show()
   {
    alert("here");
    var frm = document.western.sfrom;
    var to = document.western.sto;
    var time1 = document.western.time1;
    
    if(frm.value==to.value)
     {
      alert("Source and destination can not be the same");
      return false;
     }
      
    
    populateList('http://118.139.185.240/transferjunction/popup1.php?act=LOCAL_TRAIN&frm='+frm.value+'&to='+to.value+'&time1='+time1.value+'','design');
   }
   
   
  
    

 </script>

Comment: can you format your code so that can read it .. plus am not sure if your using jquery or a native javascript code .. from what i have read its a native javascript code .. right ?